# The Dalokohs Bar - HP Buff calculation and mechanics

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-heavy

I just FINALLY received this item last night and seeing as I'm a fairly frequent Heavy player, I'm curious as to the mechanics of the HP boost.

- Does the HP boost stack with the medic-gun, giving you a feasible 500 point health pool?
- After the buff duration expires, do you automatically lose 50 HP no matter what HP you were at originally, or will it only remove up to 50 so that you're sitting at 300 ( - 450 if being healed by a medic at the time)?
- Similarly, if you're brought below 300 HP while the buff lasts and then pick up a health pack / resupply / sit on a dispenser, will you go up to 350, or only 300 (again, more if being healed by a medic).
- If it removes 50 regardless of your current HP total, is it possible to outright die when it expires if you are sub 50 HP? Or will it leave you at 1?

Short version, does the bar give you +50 max HP for the duration, or a one-time 50 HP boost?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The HP Boost does not stack with the medic-gun.

It heals for 60 HP, and bumps the max HP by 50.  At the end of the 30 seconds, the extra 50 HP disappear immediately.  If you are above 300 HP at the time, you are reduced to 300 HP (assuming no over-heal). Otherwise, there is no change for your current HP.

If you are currently buffed to 350 by the bar, a health-pack or resupply cabinet will heal you up to 350 HP.  However, it appears that dispensers will only heal you back to the original 300.

There is more detail at the [official wiki](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Dalokohs_Bar).